# How to install mysql server

Tags: mysql

When I try to download something, I use

```
sudo apt-get install/upgrade <package>
```

However, this gives me error messages:

```
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

and when I want to download mysql server it gives me this error messages:

```
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Answer (score 0):

For example for Ubuntu you need run in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Start the MySQL service:

```
systemctl start mysql
```